# how to change background of chart in chart.js with condition

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, virtualization

I use Chart.js to create the vertical bar of my chart. I want to show the amount of codes 3 developers developed in a specific time. I want to differentiate the three developers by the three different colours. Like this...
[image]

```
import { Chart } from "chart.js/auto";

(async function () {
const data = [
{
  filename: "center.js",
  developer: ["John"],
  lastedit: "01-01-2022",
  lines: [40],
 },
 {
  filename: "collide.js",
  developer: ["Alex"],
  lastedit: "15-02-2022",
  lines: [70],
  },
  {
  filename: "constant.js",
  developer: ["Bob"],
  lastedit: "25-02-2022",
  lines: [10],
  },
  {
  filename: "index.js",
  developer: ["Alex"],
  lastedit: "17-03-2022",
  lines: [8],
  },
  {
  filename: "jiggle.js",
  developer: ["Bob"],
  lastedit: "19-03-2022",
  lines: [5],
  },
  {
  filename: "link.js",
  developer: ["Bob", "Alex", "John"],
  lastedit: "29-03-2022",
  lines: [120],
  },
  {
  filename: "manyBody.js",
  developer: ["Bob", "John"],
  lastedit: "09-04-2022",
  lines: [180],
  },
  {
  filename: "simulation.js",
  developer: ["Alex", "Bob", "John"],
  lastedit: "01-05-2022",
  lines: [140],
  },
  {
  filename: "x.js",
  developer: ["Bob"],
  lastedit: "03-05-2022",
  lines: [80],
  },
  ];

 new Chart(document.getElementById("acquisitions"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: data.map((row) => row.lastedit),
    datasets: [
    {
      label: "The amount of codes",

      data: data.map((row) => row.lines),

      backgroundColor: ["#f38b4a", "#56d798", "#6970d5"],
    },
    ],
   },
   });
  })();
```

My goal is the color of each bar in this chart can change based on the 3 different developers name. **So, how can we provide an if for the background colours?**

Answer (score 1):

backgroundColor is not array of string but just string.

```
backgroundColor: "#f38b4a".
```

Also Dataset is your array of objects which should represent the dataset of each developer. I am giving you an example.

```
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: data.map((row) => row.lastedit),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Alex',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)"
    }, {
      label: 'Bob',
      data: [30, 29, 5, 5, 20, 3, 10],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)"
    },
    {
      label: 'John',
      data: [30, 29, 5, 5, 20, 3, 10],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,255,1)"
    }]
  }
});
```

data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 28, 24, 7] =>  this is array of line edits let's say Alex did each day, the index represents day number and value of that index represents the lines edited by Alex.

let's say on day 2 (index 1 or date: 15-02-2022 as show in pic) alex wrote 19 lines of code.

this snippet should return something like this
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to read the number of codes each developed from constant data, how could I do that? I mean, I want to use data.map function for the number of lines as you did for lastedit. In this case, how can I use it for data : ...